# How to turn mojibake text to readable form?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, conversion

I got [mojibake text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) (from MP3 ID3 fields) that need to be converted to the right form.

I tried to:

```
echo 'c2 8d 44 e2 80 99 c2 b2 c2 8d 44 e2 80 99 c2 b2' | xxd -p -r | iconv -f sjis -t utf8; echo
```

but avail, I get wrong output 「ﾂ好窶卍ｲﾂ好窶卍ｲ」

How to get from that to utf8 「好調好調」?

'Text' string can be got from 
`echo 'c2 8d 44 e2 80 99 c2 b2 c2 8d 44 e2 80 99 c2 b2' | xxd -p -r`

other wierd string is

"string" `"Œã‚ëŒü‚«ˆêl”½È‰ïIE–¼ì‘I"` or as hex `c5 92 c3 a3 e2 80 9a c3 ab c5 92 c3 bc e2 80 9a c2 ab cb 86 c3 aa c2 90 6c e2 80 9d c2 bd c2 8f c3 88 e2 80 b0 c3 af c2 81 49 c2 81 45 e2 80 93 c2 bc c2 8d c3 ac e2 80 98 49`

Comment: Try it backwards -- convert FROM sjis TO utf-8: `... | iconv -f sjis -t utf-8` => `ﾂ好窶卍ｲﾂ好窶卍ｲ` (no idea if that makes any sense, though ;-)).

Comment: That assumes that your locale is `something.UTF-8`. If not, try `iconv -f sjis -t euc-jp`.

Comment: It should probably turn into [絶好調](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKuwibOMcH0), something happened with those bytes along the way.

Comment: I think text should be `好調好調`.

Comment: so question is how to get from that text string to utf8 '好調好調'.

Comment: A way I could get that is with `... | iconv -f utf-8 -t georgian-academy | iconv -f sjis -t utf-8`, which is quite absurd ;-) (`georgian-ps` also works, btw). If you have more examples, please add them to your Q.

Comment: "string" `"Œã‚ëŒü‚«ˆêl”½È‰ïIE–¼ì‘I"` or hex `c5 92 c3 a3 e2 80 9a c3 ab c5 92 c3 bc e2 80 9a  c2 ab cb 86 c3 aa c2 90 6c e2 80 9d c2 bd c2 8f  c3 88 e2 80 b0 c3 af c2 81 49 c2 81 45 e2 80 93  c2 bc c2 8d c3 ac e2 80 98 49` I got hex from `echo -n "Œã‚ëŒü‚«ˆêl”½È‰ïIE–¼ì‘I" | od -A n -t x1`

Comment: I got `.. | iconv -f utf-8 -t georgian-academy | iconv -f sjis -t utf-8` work on first name but not an another ? `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 2`.

Comment: I wasn't able to get anything from your second string by guessing; I'll try to "fuzz" it when I get time. Of course, it would help if you knew what it should turn into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mosvy your comment helped me found right names.

`... | iconv -f utf-8 -t georgian-academy | iconv -f sjis -t utf-8` > `好調好調`

but I couldn't get right string out from hex `c5 92 c3 a3 e2 80 9a c3 ab c5 92 c3 bc e2 80 9a c2 ab cb 86 c3 aa c2 90 6c e2 80 9d c2 bd c2 8f c3 88 e2 80 b0 c3 af c2 81 49 c2 81 45 e2 80 93 c2 bc c2 8d c3 ac e2 80 98 49` as `後ろ向き一人反省会！・名作選` as it should be.

In deed quite absurd.